# Is this transformation surjective?

Tags: integration, transformation

Consider the transformation $T:C_{\mathbb R} [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ defined by $T(f(t)) = \int_0^1 f(t)dt$. Is this transformation surjective? It would be enough to show that $$\mathbb{R} \subseteq\textrm{Ran}(T) = \bigg\{\int_0^1 f(t)\,dt : f(t)\in C_{\mathbb R} [0,1] \bigg\} .$$
Intuitively, this appears to be true since we should always be able to find a function that is large enough such that its integral is the desired real number. I have been trying to think on where to start for the last hours or so, any theorems or hints that might help me get started would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following result:

> Let $V$  be a vector space over a field $F$. Any linear transformation (functional) $T:V\to F$ is either **zero linear map** or **surjective**.

**Proof:** Since $T$ is a linear map, $\operatorname{Range}(T)$ is a subspace of $F$. Since the only subspaces of $F$  is either the zero subspace $\{0\}$ or $F$ itself. So the the possibilities for $\operatorname{Range}(T)$ is either $\{0\}$ (and in this case $T=0$) or $\operatorname{Range}(T)=F$ (and in this case $T$ is surjective). This completes the proof.

The above result can be restated as

> Any  **non-zero** linear functional $T:V\to F$  is **surjective**.

For your problem, take $V=(C[0,1],\Bbb R)$ and $F=\Bbb R$ and $T:V\to \Bbb F$ defined by $T(f)=\int\limits_0^1{f(t)dt}$, then clearly $T$ is a non-zero linear map, as $T(f)=1$ with $f(t)=1$, so by the above $T$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Let $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Define $$f_c(t) := c \quad\forall t \in [0,1]$$ Then we have $T(c) = c$, hence T is surjective.

Remark: More generally, every linear functional $T \neq 0$ is surjective. It's not hard to prove this.